# Vertical content alignment across the whole row

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have the following code:

```
<div class="card text-white bg-primary">
    <div class="card-body pb-0">
      <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
              <h5 class="card-title">Some Title</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

That would look like this:

[image]

What I need is to vertically adjust bottoms of texts across the whole row. Preferably using first column as an anchor. Any idea how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should zero out the margin bottom on the h5 (`mb-0`), and then use `align-items-center` on the `row`..

```
  <div class="card text-white bg-primary">
    <div class="card-body py-2">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h5 class="card-title mb-0">Some Title</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/UOB796lkRG)

Comment: While it definitely does the trick, are you sure it adjusts text bottoms? Looks like it does vertical centers, although I might be wrong.

Comment: Yes, it does vertical center. The buttons have vertical padding too so you'd have to remove that if you want the text exactly aligned.